# change x tick labels in bar plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to change the x tick labels in a bar plot using ggplot2 in R. I am making a bar plot from a double containing numerical values 1, 2, 3, and 4. The bar plot just shows the amount of times that a 1, 2, 3, or 4 is repeated in the double. I would like to change the x ticks to be "Phys", "Astro", "Eng", and "STEM Other".

Without any attempt to rename the x ticks, my code is:

```r
career_list_ms_c %>% as.data.frame %>%
  rename(Var='.') %>%
  group_by(Var) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Var, y=N)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color='black') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format(accuracy = 2))
```

With this, I get the
[image: following plot].
I have tried adding a line at the end of the above codeblock:

```r
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Phys",  "Astro", "Eng","STEM Other"))
```

With this line included, now
[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD4e3.png) doesn't have x tick labels.

I have tried similar variations of the last line, including:

```r
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Phys" = "1",  "Astro"="2", "Eng"="3",
                          "STEM Other"="4"))
```

I did see other posts asking this same question, but the answers there and in other forums all listed this use of scale_x_discrete as the solution to the problem, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Try `scale_x_continuous(labels=c("Phys",  "Astro", "Eng","STEM Other"))`

Comment: Your `Var` data is numeric -- ie the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 -- and not the characters / categories "1", "2", "3", "4." So you need to use `scale_x_continuous`; `scale_x_discrete` is for discrete data, like character or factor data.